# Multiple join tables with sum

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to join following tables

1. table_quotation
2. table_customer
3. table_project
4. table_quoted_products
5. table_estimate

here table_quoted_products has one to many relation with table_quotation
similarly each product in table_quoted_products have multiple items in table_estimate. So, 1 quotation may have multiple products in table_quoted_products and every product my have multiple items in table_estimate to build the estimated cost for each item.

Now I need a query to build a table which can give me quotation title from table_project, customer name from table_customer, total amount of quoted sale value from table_quotation and total cost for the same quotation from table_estimate. I have tried following query but sum function is multiplying by number of products.

```
SELECT a.quote_id
     , a.check_status
     , a.approve_status
     , b.title as project
     , c.customer
     , SUM(d.quantity*d.quoted_rate) as sale
     , SUM(e.qty*e.rate) as cost from table_quotation a 
  JOIN table_project b on a.project_id = b.project_id
  JOIN table_customer c on a.customer_id = c.id 
  JOIN table_quoted_product d on a.quote_id = d.quote_id 
  JOIN table_estimate e on a.quote_id = e.ref_id 
 WHERE e.ref_type = 2 and a.approve_status = 0 
 GROUP 
    BY a.quote_id
```

Estimate table has 2 kind of estimation, 1 is for template product for a single unit and 2 is for quoted products, so i need cost for only quoted products. Where I need to change to get exact sale and estimated cost?

Comment: One of my pet hates is tables called 'table_something'. And a table called 01c_something just fills me with dread :-(

Comment: made correction...any solution?

Comment: In table_estimate how do you differentiate between template product and quoted product? Do you have any column for that? If yes then add it to where clause.

Comment: I would suggest you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ref_type is differentiating both, it is already added in where clause - last para i have explained